# Github community edition installed but not open properly

Tags: centos-6, github

I am trying the install the Github lab community edition in our centos server by using steps that mentioned in the below link
https://about.gitlab.com/install/#centos-6
The installation successfully completed while we trying the access the URL its shows "404" found. I need to access the GitHub using a relative path (http://IP/githublab. Also tried to configure the relative path by using methods that mentioned below link. But still not working.
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#loading-external-configuration-file-from-non-root-user
Please anyone guide me to address this issue.

Comment: Try http://IP/gitlab

Comment: I tried this method. still, it shows "404 error". Please suggest a way to address it.